# How realize form success notify using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have feedback non-ajax form whitch create on CodeIgniter 2. I wanna to show notify after form successful submit. How do this, correctly?

Comment: I hate to give you a canned response, but **what have you tried**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic example, this is over-simplified so it can be understood easily:

Controller

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) // Your logic that tells if the submit was OK
{
    $data['message'] = 'Thanks.';
}
else
{
    $data['message'] = 'There was an error.';
}
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

View

```
<?php echo $message; ?>
```